# AVAudioSession Passcode-lock stops AVAudioRecorder on iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio-recording, avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession

I’m having unexpected issues related to background recording (specifically when the Screen becomes *Passcode-locked*). In Summary my *AVAudioRecorder* app seems to record correctly in the foreground, background (when switching apps) and when the screen is off (but before the pass-lock is activated).

If i delay passcode-lock (*Settings > Passcode > Require Passcode > 4 hours .etc*) then the recording works without a problem in foreground/background/app switching/screen off .etc, but when the pass-lock kicks in the recording becomes corrupt.

I'm basically using *AVAudioRecorder* code to record the audio, and have followed the guidelines by setting 'UIBackgroundModes/audio' setting in app.plist to ensure background recording, which seems to work in the background (i.e. Red Recording Bar appears) but fails when pass-code becomes active i.e. user pushes the power button and is required to enter a passcode to access the device.

My code is set to handle audio-interrupts via ‘*AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification*’ and AVAudioSession is setup ‘*withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDuckOthers*’ to minimise outside events from effecting background recording.

**[ Testing Procedure ]**

- Passcode-lock (iPhone 5/iOS8.1 > Settings > Passcode > Require Passcode > After 5 minutes)

  1. [Success-CASE-1] ‘Start Recording’ for 7mins Leave Screen On and App active/visible (i.e. not running in background after recording is started) >> Recording works and after pressing ‘Stop Recording’ audio is saved and can be played back.
  2. [Success-CASE-2] ‘Start Recording’ for 7mins Leave Screen On and Switch apps (i.e. run in background with screen mostly On and Red-Recording bar displayed after recording is started) >> Recording works and after pressing ‘Stop Recording’ audio is saved and can be played back.
  3. [Failure-CASE] ‘Start Recording’ for 7mins Switch Screen Off (i.e. app is running in background with devices screen off) >> After 7mins with Screen-Off, device requires passcode when screen is switched-On. Recording unexpectedly stops, becomes corrupt cannot be played back.
- Passcode-lock (iPhone 5/iOS8.1> Settings > Passcode > Require Passcode > After 15 minutes)

  1. [Repeat-Failure-CASE with Adjusted Passlock] ‘Start Recording’ for 7mins Switch Screen Off (i.e. app is running in background with devices screen off) >> After 7mins with Screen-Off, device is switched on (no pass lock is needed this time). Recording is okay, works perfectly and can be played back.

Only difference between Failure-CASE and Repeat-Failure-CASE is the screen-lock passcode was not required.

**[ Notes ]**

1. Tested using XCode 6.1, on iPhone 4/5/6, iPad Mini 2 (iOS8.1) with same issue.
2. Code is standard AVAudioRecorder code, with AVAudioSession setup similar to:
   http://www.jacopretorius.net/2013/04/record-and-playback-audio-in-ios.html

**..**

Hope the info helps, took a lot of trial and error to get to this point.

has anyone else experienced this issue? as its quite strange.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your audio file（in sandbox） maybe is protected by iOS when passcode-lock;
If the screen is locked without a passcode set,  everything is ok；

Try the below：

```
        NSDictionary *oldAttr = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]attributesOfItemAtPath:localFilePath error:nil];
        NSMutableDictionary *newAttr = nil;
        if (oldAttr){
            newAttr = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:oldAttr];
        }else{
            newAttr = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        }
        [newAttr setObject:NSFileProtectionNone forKey:NSFileProtectionKey];
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] setAttributes:newAttr
                                         ofItemAtPath:localFilePath
                                                error:nil];
```

Or，set your Data-protection in Certificate to close。

Comment: Man u saved my life.... thanks for this, have been searching for a while for the cause of this issue! Apple seems to be getting worser and worser day by day, there was not even a log message describing what the problem was!